# WhatsApp Archive Issue

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger

I'm running WhatsApp on Android 8.

I've archived all my chats on WhatsApp , and I have continuous automatic backups switched on. Will the archives and their media also be backed up on WhatsApp along with all other chats and all other media ?  Is there anything specific I should know ? This is the first time that I've archived anything on WhatsApp.

Any help and shedding some light on the question and related issues would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. **All** contents of WhatsApp including archived chats media , messages, audio notes will be backed up to Google Drive

I have done backing up and restoring multiple times so can absolutely confirm